# Sigma Notation Sum of 1 = n prove statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am bit new to sigma notations .. and i don't know why Summing 1 equals n

[image]

any great minds here ? Thanks

Comment: Not yet, but I already saw the expanded form with the answer below..

Comment: I noticed. Just keep in mind that a good trick when doing these kinds of problems is to expand out the terms and analyse what the series looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$$
where $a_k:=1$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Here the value of $a_k$ does not depend on $k$ ($a_k$ is *constant*), but you still have to add it $n$ times :
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k &= a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n\\
&= 1 + 1 + \cdots +1 \qquad \text{$n$ times} \\
&= n.
\end{align}

Comment: I see,
so the value of k is 1 - n ?

Comment: @waelhe I don't understand what you mean by that. $n$ is a fixed natural number. $k$ is an index. When I write $1 \leq k \leq n$ I mean that $k$ goes from $1$ to $n$, that is, I'm saying $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1, \ldots, a_{n-1}=1, a_n=1$.

Comment: @Guest- sorry, i mean 1 to n :) not 1 minus n .. anyways, thanks a lot cause I already figured it out with your answer.

Comment: @waelhe Ah, well. I would have said "$k$ takes *values* from $1$ to $n$", since $k$ doesn't take a single value. Anyway, glad this helped.

Answer (score 1):

The notation means adding 1's n times so it is $n *1=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n1=1+1+\dots +1=n.$$